# Execute a report program on radio button with validations?

Tags: report, abap, dynpro

I am trying to run 2 report programs, **REPORTS_1** and **REPORTS_2**. The first program **REPORTS_1** should only be executed **if the first radio button is selected and all the parameters are filled in**(parameter fields are always mandatory?). And the second program **REPORTS_2 should only be executed if the second radio button is selected and all the corresponding parameters are filled in**. Below is the code. Is this the place and correct way to call SUBMIT?

```
* Selection screen 1
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK flight_block WITH FRAME TITLE text-002.
    PARAMETERS: carrid TYPE sbook-carrid MODIF ID sc1.
    PARAMETERS: connid TYPE sbook-connid MODIF ID sc1.
    PARAMETERS: fldate TYPE sbook-fldate MODIF ID sc1.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK flight_block.
```

```
*Selection screen 2
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK customid_block WITH FRAME TITLE text-003.
    PARAMETERS: customid TYPE sbook-customid MODIF ID sc2.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK customid_block.
```

```
AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
* Toggle the selection screens based on radio buttons
 LOOP AT SCREEN.
     IF rad_flt = 'X' AND screen-group1 = 'SC2'.
         PERFORM modify_screen. "Calling subroutine
         SUBMIT Z15081947_MINI_REPORTS_1 AND RETURN. " Issue???
     ELSEIF rad_cus = 'X' AND screen-group1 = 'SC1'.
         PERFORM modify_screen. "Calling subroutine
         SUBMIT Z15081947_MINI_REPORTS_2 AND RETURN. " Issue???
     ENDIF.
 ENDLOOP.
```

```
* Subroutines.
FORM modify_screen.
 screen-active = 0.
 MODIFY SCREEN.
ENDFORM.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the radiobutton declaration. I assume it's something like:

```
PARAMETERS rad_flt type char01 RADIOBUTTON GROUP g1 DEFAULT 'X' USER-COMMAND RAD.
PARAMETERS rad_cus type char01 RADIOBUTTON GROUP g1.
```

Here the `USER-COMMAND RAD` part triggers a PBO/PAI immediately after a radiobutton change.

About the call of the reports: the event `AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT` is not the proper place for a `SUMBIT` statement, since it will be called at PBO, potentially not allowing the user to display the selection screen at all.

It's a more common practice to only change the screen fields (fields deactivation) in `AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT`

```
AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
* Toggle the selection screens based on radio buttons
   LOOP AT SCREEN.
     IF rad_flt = 'X' AND screen-group1 = 'SC2'.
         PERFORM modify_screen. "Calling subroutine
     ELSEIF rad_cus = 'X' AND screen-group1 = 'SC1'.
         PERFORM modify_screen. "Calling subroutine
     ENDIF.
 ENDLOOP.
```

and to perform the remaining logic in `START-OF-SELECTION` part for example:

```
START-OF-SELECTION.
  CASE 'X'.
  WHEN rad_flt.
    IF carrid IS NOT INITIAL AND
       connid IS NOT INITIAL AND
       fldate IS NOT INITIAL.
      SUBMIT Z15081947_MINI_REPORTS_1 AND RETURN.
    ENDIF.
  WHEN rad_cus.
    IF customid IS NOT INITIAL.
      SUBMIT Z15081947_MINI_REPORTS_2 AND RETURN.
    ENDIF.
  ENDCASE.
```

Comment: For more information about the **reporting events** and **selection screen events**, refer to the [ABAP documentation - Flow of an executable program](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenreporting_process.htm).